# combine each do |f| with link_to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Maybe this is a crazy question but what I want to do is have a list of all the users on an account and have a link next to each user that removes that user from the account.  More specifically the link, when clicked, changes the account_id to 0 instead of whatever # it used to be.  I have this nice list of account users with a "remove this user" link next to each user on the account show page:

```
  <% @account.users.each do |f| %> 
     <ul> <h2><%= f.name %> |
              <%= f.email %> |
              <%= f.account_id %> </h2>
              <%= link_to "Remove this user",  user_path(@user, :user => { :account_id => 0}),
             :method => :put %> </ul>
<% end %>
```

But when I hover over the link it always shows the route of the current user and updates the current user's account_id.  I've been messing around with various solutions but can't seem to get the link to update the attribute of the listed user (from @account.users.each) instead of the current user.  Is this even possible?  Many thanks!

Comment: Better to do it on ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Any chance you can elaborate or point me towards a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @account.users.each do |f| %> 
     <ul> <h2><%= f.name %> |
              <%= f.email %> |
              <%= f.account_id %> </h2>
              <%= link_to "Remove this user",  user_path(f, :user => { :account_id => 0}),
             :method => :put %> </ul>
<% end %>
```

@user will be current user and that is why it is updating current user

Comment: Works perfectly!  I couldn't figure out where to put the f, this makes perfect sense.  Many thanks!